# Use Image as Button and Toggle Image on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found quite a bit on how to solve this problem, but I can't seem to get it working. I want to use an image that has the functionality of a button. The following code works well, but is neither great style, nor will it be able to switch the image it uses.

```
<input type="image" id="mToggle" src="images/chevronright.jpg" width="48" height="48"></input>
```

I should be able to do something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" id="mToggle" class="right" width="48" height="48"></input>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
    background-image: url("images/chevronLeft.jpg");
}

.right{
    background-image: url("images/chevronRight.jpg");
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#mToggle").click(function(){
    $('#mToggle').toggleClass('left');
});
```

This should give me a button that is initially a right arrow and will swap between left and right every time upon the click.

Edit: I should mention that the second method that I described only results in the default "Submit Query" text appearing for the  No picture is displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: input id is missing a ", also I'd also toggleClass('right')

Comment: That was a typo on my part. It was correct in the code. I've tried both with and without quotes inside of toggleClass

Comment: maybe remove the src.. and set id="mToggle" your html is not right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os7svkw1/1/)** of your code :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="image" id="mToggle" class="right" width="64" height="64" value=' '></input>
```

**JS :**

Just add the **[ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)** funciton `$(function(){ });` to specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $("#mToggle").click(function(){
        $('#mToggle').toggleClass('left right');
    });
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: The text "Submit Query" still appears on my live version. Any ideas as to how to get rid of it?

Comment: appear insead the button ? try to add `value="  "` just like i added in my answer.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.